# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'firebase' when Importing FirebaseOptions in Java Project

Tags: java, firebase, gradle

I'm working on a Java project and trying to integrate Firebase. I've added the necessary dependencies to my build.gradle file, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to import `com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions` in my code. It's showing an error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'firebase'`. Here's my build.gradle file for reference:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

I've ensured that my Gradle sync is up to date, but I'm still facing this issue. How can I resolve the `Cannot resolve symbol` error and successfully import FirebaseOptions in my project?

Any help or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried adding .jar files externally to the lib folder and the project structure window, but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you added the proper import? If yes, can show that to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this in your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.3.0'
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you! I added these but some other errors are happening that I cannot figure out why

error: the unnamed module reads package com.google.longrunning from both proto.google.common.protos and gax.grpc
error: module javafx.controlsEmpty reads package io.grpc from both grpc.api and grpc.context
error: module google.api.client.gson reads package io.grpc from both grpc.api and grpc.context

Here are some of them.

Comment: Hi, you acepted the answer, did it work for you?

Comment: I added these but some other errors are happening that I cannot figure out why error: the unnamed module reads package com.google.longrunning from both proto.google.common.protos and gax.grpc error: module javafx.controlsEmpty reads package io.grpc from both grpc.api and grpc.context error: module google.api.client.gson reads package io.grpc from both grpc.api and grpc.context Here are some of them.

Comment: change it to `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0`

Comment: It says: Could not find method compile()